# What do I need to replace Cranium: Turbo Edition's electronic timer?

Tags: cranium

I picked up Cranium: Turbo Edition at a yard sale for a couple dollars, and everything is in great condition except that the electronic timer centerpiece is missing. I figured I could replace the color selection and timer functionality with the die and hourglass from my copy of the original game, but is there any other functionality that I'm missing out on? Is the length of the electronic timer the same as the old hourglass? Are the color probabilities the same as an old die roll?

Comment: @diego - Thanks! I was surprised at the lack of a Cranium tag at first, but I guess there isn't really that much to ask about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Turbo rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/BD640679-D56F-E112-4AAD860D844EDC4C.pdf), the electronic timer lasts 60 seconds. This is the same as the egg timer in the base game.

I can't speak to the colour probabilities or guarantee that there isn't a mechanism to (for example) ensure that a mix of colours comes up, but I think uniformly randomly choosing a colour is a fair and fine way of doing it.

Comment: Great! We've been playing it with the old timer and die and it's been working perfectly. :)